# Как привести nvarchar формата 2022-02-06 19:01:09.639 UTC к формату Datetime или Date в MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как привести nvarchar формата `2022-02-06 19:01:09.639 UTC` к формату Datetime или Date в MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATETIME устаревший формат, лучше DATETIME2:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('2022-02-06 19:01:09.639 UTC', 23) AS DATETIME2(3))
```

Если нужна только дата, то:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('2022-02-06 19:01:09.639 UTC', 23) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Или даже `DATETIMEOFFSET` для сохранения часового пояса.